# Why can't I catch this exception? (C++, SFML)

Tags: c++, exception, sfml, uncaught-exception

Maybe it's a stupid question but I don't understand why I can catch the exception in the former piece of code, while I can't in the latter.

First piece of code:

```
int main() {
    try {
        throw std::logic_error("Error");
        sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Test", sf::Style::Default);
        while (window.isOpen()) {
            sf::Event event;
            while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
                if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                    window.close();
            }
            
            window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
            window.display();
        }
    }
    catch(std::logic_error& l){
        std::cerr<<l.what()<<std::endl;
        exit(42);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Second piece of code:

```
int main() {
    try {
       
        sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Test", sf::Style::Default);
        throw std::logic_error("Error");
        while (window.isOpen()) {
            sf::Event event;
            while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
                if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                    window.close();
            }

            window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
            window.display();
        }
    }
    catch(std::logic_error& l){
        std::cerr<<l.what()<<std::endl;
        exit(42);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI, it is generally preferrable to catch exceptions by `const` reference instead of non-const, eg: `catch(const std::logic_error& l)`

Answer (score 1):

Probably, because `sf::RenderWindow` throws exception of another type earlier.

Try catching `std::exception`, not `std::logic_error` (it's inherited from `std::exception`)

**Update**

Probably your app is crashing during `sf::RenderWindow` initialization. In this case exception is not generated, but you can try to catch signal.

```
#include <signal.h>

void fall()
{
      int* p = 0x00000000; 
      *p = 13;
}

void posix_death_signal(int signum)
{
    signal(signum, SIG_DFL);
    exit(3);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    signal(SIGSEGV, posix_death_signal);
    fall();
    return 0;
}
```

Or maybe `std::abort` is called from `sf::RenderWindow`, so you can try to handle it: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort

Or `std::unexpected`. You can try to handle it also

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/unexpected
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/set_unexpected

`std::exit`...

Actually I would like to advice attach debugger and see what happens, see how far is running your app before returning

**Update 2**

Sometimes the root problem is missing DLL which prevents app from starting.

Comment: `std::logic_error` does inherit from `std::exception` but if the other exception does not you will still miss it

Comment: I tried even to write `catch(...)` but I see no changes.

Comment: @NiccolòNiccoli I've added more info

Answer (score 1):

At the end I've discovered that the problem regarded how I had linked the SFML library.
I just had to remove `-static` from `target_link_libraries(SFML_Test sfml-system sfml-window sfml-graphics -static)` in the CMake file.
Thank you to everyone who has tried to help me.